# Get array value when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to get single value from array which is in other file, this is my code so far

```
     $data = file_get_contents('order.log', true);
$name = $data['0']['customer_last_name'];
echo $name;
```

**And this is part of my array file:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customer_id] => 1364
            [customer_group_id] => 1
            [customer_first_name] => penna
            [customer_last_name] => Macii
            [customer_email] => mail8@abv.bg
            [customer_ip] => 1601136638
            [note_customer] => 
            [note_administrator] => 
            [quantity] => 3
            [weight] => 0
            [vat_included] => yes
            [email_sent] => 
            [status] => pending
            [customer_geoip] => Array
                (
                    [city] => Sofia
                    [state] => Sofia-Capital
                    [country] => Bulgaria
                    [country_iso] => BG
                    [timeZone] => Europe/Sofia
                    [lon] => 42.683
                    [lat] => 23.3175
                )
```

**OUTPUT IS**

```
 A
```

Comment: $data = file_get_contents('order.log', true); return a string, not an array

Comment: A is from Array the first letter of this string

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [customer_id] => 1364 [customer_group_id] => 1 [customer_first_name] => penna [customer_last_name] => Macii [customer_email] => mail8@abv.bg [customer_ip] => 1601136638 [note_customer] => [note_administrator] => [quantity] => 3 [weight] => 0 [vat_included] => yes [email_sent] => [status] => pending [customer_geoip] => Array ( [city] => Sofia [state] => Sofia-Capital [country] => Bulgaria [country_iso] => BG [timeZone] => Europe/Sofia [lon] => 42.683 [lat] => 23.3175 ) ) )

Comment: The `print_r` format (that's what this is) cannot be extracted back easily. Fix your storage approach first.